# Accessing HTML Table data in Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, xcode

I am relatively new at coding in swift and am having some confusion about GET requests. Here is my goal: I want to fetch some data that is in a table on a website using swift and display it in an iOS app. I know how to make the iOS table once I have the data. What I don't understand is how to get that data using an HTML GET request.

The data that I am trying to access is formatted in HTML as follows:

```
<tr class="white_text">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1464</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>9.86</td>
    <td>3.85</td>
    <td>1228</td>
    <td>28</td>
</tr>
```

This data is repeated multiple times in the same format but with different information.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The data shouldn't be coming back as raw HTML. It should be coming back as JSON. What does the data look like when it's returned from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it true that you should send JSON to you app. But if there is no other way you can download HTML data into a string and then parse it using one of the pod libraries available. For this purpose I used hpple.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do something like this instead, there are loads of options and possibities as everything is kinda custom depends how you apply it.

```
    // This custom HTML says that the web page fits mobile divices
    let html = """
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style> body { font-size: 150% } </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    \(detailItem.body)
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    
    webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil) // This method will read the HTML string. Note: that"detailItem is an array of containing parsed JSON data already so I've combined it with HTML and this method will do that rest.

}
```